# Programmatically set constraints for uitableviewcell with uilabel and uiimageview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to build my tableview with custom UITableViewCell but facing some issues in coinstraints. Following is my custom UITablviewCell class:

```
class MovieCell: UITableViewCell {
static let identifier = "MovieCell"
let cellMargin = 15.0

private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    return view
}()

private let movieNameLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.movieAppBoldFont(size: 15)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

private let movieImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

var movieCellViewModel : MoviewCellViewModel = MoviewCellViewModel(image: nil, name: "") {
    didSet {
        movieNameLabel.text = movieCellViewModel.name
    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    layoutSubView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func layoutSubView() {
    addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(movieNameLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(movieImageView)
    
    let marginGuide = containerView.layoutMarginsGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -cellMargin),
        
        movieImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
        movieImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
        movieImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        movieImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

        movieNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
        movieNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
        movieNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        movieNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
    ])
}
```

}

I get the following result with the above code:
[image]

I am trying to create a UIView and add content to it. I am adding it because I want to show some empty space as a separator in tableview.

Answer (score 1):

Couple issues...

Your first line in `layoutSubView()` is:

```
addSubview(containerView)
```

where is needs to be:

```
contentView.addSubview(containerView)
```

Second, you have `movieImageView` constrained to `contentView`:

```
movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
```

where it should be constrained to `marginGuide`:

```
movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
```

Third, you have `movieNameLabel.leadingAnchor` constrained to `marginGuide.trailingAnchor`:

```
movieNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
```

where it should be constrained to `movieImageView.trailingAnchor`:

```
movieNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
```

Making those changes will give you this (I set image view background to blue, and label background to cyan):

[image]

However, when you run the app, you'll see lots of ***Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.*** messages. This is common when using subviews with subviews in cells.

To get rid of the auto-layout complaints, we can give the `containerView` bottom anchor a less-than-required priority:

```
let bottomC = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -cellMargin)
bottomC.priority = .required - 1
```

and then activate that in your constraints block:

```
//containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -cellMargin),
bottomC,
```

Here's your complete `MovieCell` class with those changes:

```
class MovieCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "MovieCell"
    let cellMargin = 15.0
    
    private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()
    
    private let movieNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold) // UIFont.movieAppBoldFont(size: 15)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    
    private let movieImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()
    
    var movieCellViewModel : MoviewCellViewModel = MoviewCellViewModel(image: nil, name: "") {
        didSet {
            movieNameLabel.text = movieCellViewModel.name
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
        layoutSubView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func layoutSubView() {
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(movieNameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(movieImageView)
        
        let marginGuide = containerView.layoutMarginsGuide
    
        let bottomC = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -cellMargin)
        bottomC.priority = .required - 1

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
//          containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -cellMargin),
            bottomC,
            
            movieImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            movieImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5),
//          movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            movieImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            movieImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
//          movieNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            movieNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            movieNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            movieNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            movieNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
        ])

        // during dev, so we can easily see the frames
        movieImageView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        movieNameLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }
}
```